# Are There Any Server Options for ASP.NET Other Than IIS and Apache?

Tags: asp.net

Curious as to if ASP.NET is compatible with any other web servers out there (ie. node.js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search revealed there are a few other options:

- [Aprelium](http://www.aprelium.com/abyssws/aspnet/)
- [Neokernal](http://www.neokernel.com/content.agent?page_name=Home)
- [Casssini](http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/)
- [Cherokee](http://cherokee-project.com/doc/cookbook_mono.html)

IIS is still probably the way to go though for asp.net. I'm not a Node expert but from my understanding Node.JS is not related to asp.net. Scott Hanselman wrote [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx) blog post on how to get Node.JS running on Windows through IIS, I've just skimmed the article but you might find it interesting.